# Statistics Normal probility

Tags: statistics

A chromosome mutation believed to be linked with color blindness is known to
occur, on the average, once in every 10,000 births. If 200,000 babies are born
this year in a certain city, use Normal distribution to estimate the probability
that at least 16 will develop color blindness. What is the exact probability model
that applies here? Find the exact probability that at least 16 will develop color
blindness.

how do in do this in my calculator?

the answer is .843

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$p = 1/10000 = 10^{-4} \ll 1.\quad$ $N = 200000 = 2\times 10^{5}.\quad$
$\angles{n} = Np = 20$:
$$
1 - \sum_{n = 0}^{15}{\expo{-\angles{n}}\angles{n}^{n} \over n!}
=
1 - \expo{-20}\sum_{n = 0}^{15}{20^{n} \over n!}
\approx
\color{#0000ff}{\large 0.843487}
$$

We
[evaluated the right hand side](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+e%5E%7B-20%7D%5Csum_%7Bn+%3D+0%7D%5E%7B15%7D%5Cfrac%7B20%5En%7D%7Bn%21%7D+) with WA.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the probability a child comes up blind is $\frac{1}{20}$.

So the probability that 1 child comes up blind out of 100,000 is $\frac {1}{20}*{19}{20}^{199,999}*\binom{1}{200,000}$

in general the probability n child come up blind is ${1}{20}^n*{19}{20}^{(200,000-n)}*\binom{200,000}{n}$. So the total will be $1-\sum_{n=1}^{15} (\frac{1}{20})^n*(\frac {19}{20})^{(200,000-n)}*\binom{200,000}{n}$

Comment: And where did you use the normal distribution?

Comment: Oh crap. Apparently i've been tutoring someone about normal distribution without knowing what that is. well, here is an approach without normal distribution.